# External dll in javafx

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I create object of external dll(canMate.dll) in javafx? I am  able to include the dll path in javapath and load it using System.load(). How to invoke the methods involved in the dll?

Comment: why write Microsoft specific software using Java?

Comment: you can do this using Java native interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html

Comment: The user interface is in java.It needs to communicate to a device using CAN